# Limiting Checkstyle to certain packages

Tags: checkstyle, gradle-plugin

I have a project with several hundred packages. It's mostly generated code from a conversion from COBOL to inline java so the vast majority of it (~11,000 files) is something I do not want to run checkstyle on. I do have a couple packages in the project that are "real" java that I have added to replace utilities that could not be generated by the code conversion and I *do* want to run checkstyle on those.

I'm having trouble getting the suppression to work properly.

This is the relevant fragment from the checkstyle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<!--
    Checkstyle configuration that checks the Google coding conventions from Google Java Style
    that can be found at https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html.
    Checkstyle is very configurable. Be sure to read the documentation at
    http://checkstyle.sf.net (or in your downloaded distribution).
    To completely disable a check, just comment it out or delete it from the file.
    Authors: Max Vetrenko, Ruslan Diachenko, Roman Ivanov.
 -->

<module name = "Checker">
    <property name="charset" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java, properties, xml"/>
    <module name="FileTabCharacter">
        <property name="eachLine" value="true"/>
    </module>

    <module name="SuppressionFilter">
        <property name="file" value="${config_loc}/checkstyleSuppress.xml"/>
        <property name="optional" value="false"/>
    </module>
    
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="OuterTypeFilename"/>
        <module name="IllegalTokenText">
            <property name="tokens" value="STRING_LITERAL, CHAR_LITERAL"/>
            <property name="format"
             value="\\u00(09|0(a|A)|0(c|C)|0(d|D)|22|27|5(C|c))|\\(0(10|11|12|14|15|42|47)|134)"/>
            <property name="message"
             value="Consider using special escape sequence instead of octal value or Unicode escaped value."/>
        </module>
        <module name="AvoidEscapedUnicodeCharacters">
            <property name="allowEscapesForControlCharacters" value="true"/>
            <propert ...
```

I'm confident that the checkstyleSuppress.xml file is getting read because checkstyle will error out if I add a character to the file name to make it wrong.

The content of checkstyleSuppress.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
  "-//Checkstyle//DTD SuppressionFilter Configuration 1.2//EN"
  "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/suppressions_1_2.dtd">

<suppressions>
    <suppress files="[/\\].+" checks=".*"/>

    <suppress checks=".*" files="app[\\/]dbio[\\/].java"/>
    <suppress checks=".*" files="app[\\/]dbio[\\/]internal[\\/].java"/>
    <suppress checks=".*" files="app[\\/]f17*[\\/].java"/>
    <suppress checks=".*" files="app[\\/]f17*[\\/]internal[\\/].java"/>
</suppressions>
```

What I'm trying to do is suppress all checks for anything in the app.dbio and app.f17* packages. To see if my rules are running I added the first line in the file which I thought would suppress all checks on all files.

None of these filters are suppressing anything. Checkstyle checks all files in all packages (and reports over 400,000 violations, which is a bit too many to wade through for the ones I care about! lol)

Most projects are ground up, so I have previously used checkstyle with no suppression. This is my first attempt to limit the scope of the code review and it's not going as I had hoped. I'm not sure where my issue lies here.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Well.. hmmmmm... I'm checking somehting now. I was expecting it to skip the files, but it looks like it picks up the files and then skips the checks. I;ll update after verifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_filefilters.html#BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter) is the thing you are looking for. You can provide regexp(s) which matches packages you want to exclude, they will not be checked.